# Text Issue Appcompatedelegate.setDefaultNightMode in Kitkat API 19 (black on black)

Tags: android, textview, android-4.4-kitkat, android-night-mode

There's an issue in my app when night mode is on, text turn black with background black, only in KitKat API 19, please help ?? thank you

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        UiModeManager uiModeManager = (UiModeManager) getSystemService(UI_MODE_SERVICE);
        if (!mUseLayoutTheme && uiModeManager != null) {
            uiModeManager.setNightMode(mRepositorySettings.getNightMode()
                    ? UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES
                    : UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        }
    } else {
        if (!mUseLayoutTheme) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(mRepositorySettings.getNightMode()
                    ? AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
                    : AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        }

    }
```

Comment: post your code as well

Comment: edit the question post code there